# My promise in a promise is returning <pending>

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio, request-promise, node-fetch

I have this (extracts):

**index.js:**

```
searchSerial: swName => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
        const url = rawUrl + '?chto=' + swName.replace(' ','+')
        const $ = cheerio.load(await (await fetch(url)).text())
        resolve(new SearchSerial($))
    })
}
```

**SearchSerial.js:**

```
module.exports = class SearchSerial {
constructor($) {

    let key = []

    const secBypass = id => {
        return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
            const url = 'https://www.serials.ws/d.php?n=' + id
            const $ = cheerio.load(await (await fetch(url)).text())
            resolve(new SecBypass($))
        })
    }

    for (let i = 2; i < $("tbody").get(5).children.length-2; i++) {
        let id = parseInt($("tbody").get(5).children[i].children[0].children[0].attribs.href.slice(13,21))
        key.push(secBypass(id))
    }

    this.test = key

}
}
```

**SecBypass:**

```
module.exports = class SecBypass {
    constructor($) {

        this.testing = 'heyyy'

    }
}
```

But `this.test` return a list of `Promise { <pending> }`
I've tested many things, read already answered questions but found nothing.

Comment: There is no reason to manually create new `Promise` instances when `fetch` itself returns a promise

Comment: What do you expect `this.text` to actually be? With `secBypass` returning a promise and `key.push(secBypass(id))` pushing those promises into an array, it should not be surprising that you get an array of promises

Comment: Ok so what should I do? Something like this? `const secBypass = id => {
            const url = 'https://www.serials.ws/d.php?n=' + id
            const $ = cheerio.load(fetch(url))
            return new SecBypass($)
        }`, It's "working" but `$` doesn't contain the right things, for exemple: `this.test = $('body')` return `[initialize]`

Comment: [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)